# Doubt on property of cosine function

Tags: trigonometry

For the following function

$\cos(2^ix)$ ($0\le x \le 2\pi$), $i = 0,1,\dots,n$. I noticed that none of the cos curves crosses the $x$ axis at the same point.

eg:

$i=0 : \pi/2,3\pi/2$

$i=1 : \pi/4,3\pi/4,5\pi/4,7\pi/4$

$i=2 : \pi/8,3\pi/8,5\pi/8,7\pi/8,9\pi/8,11\pi/8,13\pi/8,15\pi/8$

Is my observation is correct? Or is there any theorem for this?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

Comment: There is an explicit formula for the zeros of $\cos$: $\cos(y) = 0$ iff $y\in \frac \pi 2 + \pi \mathbb Z$

Comment: @Stefan I want to know more about the sequence, whether no two function can have the same y for zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct.  Curve $i$ will cross the $x$ axis at $\frac {1+2n}{2^{i+1}}\pi$, where $n$ is any integer.  Some curve will cross the $x$ axis at any rational multiple of $\pi$.  You can determine which by finding how many factors of $2$ are in the denominator. As each rational has a unique number of factors of $2$ in the denominator, the crossings will all be distinct.